# Wgsl Naga - How can I use builtin textureStore() with texture_storage_2d<rgba8uint,write>?

Tags: shader, compute-shader, wgpu-rs

Naga validate this snippet:

```
    [[group(0), binding(0)]] var output :
    texture_storage_2d<rgba8unorm,write>;
    
    [[stage(compute), workgroup_size(1)]]
    fn main() {
        textureStore(output, vec2<i32>(10,10), vec4<f32>(10.,5.,100.,200.));
    }
```

Replacing **rgba8unorm** with **rgba8uint** makes naga throwing an error.

```
Entry point main at Compute is invalid:     The value [9] can not be stored
    Generating SPIR-V output requires validation to succeed, and it failed in a previous step
```

I tried different combinations of scalar with vec4<> in textureStore: i32,u32,f32 but no luck.

Question is: How can I use the builtin function **textureStore()** with
**texture_storage_2d<rgba8uint,write>** instead of **texture_storage_2d<rgba8unorm,write>** ?

EDIT: Following Dan answer I tried the following

```
[[group(0), binding(0)]] var output :
    texture_storage_2d<rgba8uint,write>;
    
    [[stage(compute), workgroup_size(1)]]
    fn main() {
        textureStore(output, vec2<i32>(10,10), vec4<u32>(10u,5u,10u,20u));
    }
```

It works!

I tried and failed with textureStore(output, vec2(10,10), vec4(10,5,10,20));
I forgot the **u** in 10**u**,5**u**, etc...

Thanks.

Comment: By the way, wgpu has just released version 0.12 that has massively better shader error messages. (It does have some breaking changes though, fyi.)

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking: Error messages are somewhat cryptic. The 0.12 version will be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store in a `rgba8uint`, you need to use the type `vec4<u32>`. See [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/WGSL/#storage-texel-formats) for the corresponding type for each texture storage. If that's not working, you may have a different problem. (Are you passing in `10.` etc to the `vec4<u32>`? It should be `10u`. Wgsl is very strict about types.)

Comment: You are absolutely right. Even for integer you have to be explicit in this case: You have to write `10u`  and not just `10`... Thanks a lot.